# Dockerfile script working in native Ubuntu but not in Windows or WSL

Tags: windows, bash, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my Dockerfile I have the next RUN script:

```
RUN set -ex; \
  echo "Downloading plugins"; \
  cd /tmp/plugins; \
  for f in `cat plugins.list`; do\
    curl -O -fSL $f; \
  done;
```

When I build the image from native Ubuntu it works flawlessly, but when I do it from Powershell or Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux it always gives me the same error:

```
 ---> Running in 095faf998ee4
 + echo 'Downloading plugins'
 + cd /tmp/plugins
 Downloading plugins                                                                                             
 + cat plugins.list
 ' curl -O -fS 'https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/ninja-forms.3.4.19.zip
 curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

If I run the curl command directly from bash it works flawlessly too, but if I run that part of the script it fails too.

Comment: At powershell `curl` don't work, you can use `Invoke-WebRequest`, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl

Comment: The thing is I don't expect it to work on powershell, but need it to work in wsl because the remote environment where this script has to run is Ubuntu, I need to be able to do docker-compose in windows without changing the script

Comment: Ensure that your `plugins.list` file uses Unix EOL characters, ie. ensure there is no \r in that file.

Comment: @cbley how can i check for the \r? I have two plugins.list files, one that works and one that doesn't, and in vi and in sublime text I see them equally o.O

Comment: in editors, there's usually an indication of the EOL mode of the file. Also, to get rid of them, in your shell, run `tr -d '\r' < plugins.list > plugins.list_new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cbley commented, the issue was in the EOL character, since on default sublime text on windows has EOL like windows, it was giving errors to the script.

Either replacing with `tr -d '\r' < plugins.list > plugins.list_new` as @cbley commented on my question or setting sublime text's default EOL as "Unix" by adding `"default_line_ending": "unix",` to the sublime preferences did the trick.

Thanks @cbley!